# Quicker way to implement into a list?

Tags: list, flutter, dart, radiobuttonlist

Im making a list of radio buttons. But cant figure a way to map them. The current method making one by one which is too much and with 10+ radio buttons this is taking up hundreds of lines of code.

```
enum SingingCharacter {char1, char2, char3, char4}
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  SingingCharacter _character = SingingCharacter.char1;

  final List myList= ['One','Two','Thre' ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Home'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(children: <Widget>[
            RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
              title: Text('${myList[0]}'),
              value: SingingCharacter.char1,
              groupValue: _character,
              onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                setState(() {
                  _character = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
              title: Text('${myList[1]}'),
              value: SingingCharacter.char2,
              groupValue: _character,
              onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
                setState(() {
                  _character = value;
                });
              },
            )
            ....
          ]),
        ));
  }
}
```

Any method to loop through this and show in children?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your `List` to a `Map` and then use this to map your enum values to Widgets. Like this (disclaimer: Code not tested, but something like this should be possible):

```
enum SingingCharacter {char1, char2, char3}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  SingingCharacter _character = SingingCharacter.char1;

  final Map<SingingCharacter, String> radioMap = {SingingCharacter.char1: 'One', SingingCharacter.char2: 'Two', SingingCharacter.char3: 'Three'};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Home'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: _generateRadioButtons()
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _generateRadioButtons() {
    return SingingCharacter.values.map((char) {
      return RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
        title: Text('${radioMap[char]}'),
        value: char
        groupValue: _character,
        onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
          setState(() {
            _character = value;
          });
        },
      );
    }).toList();
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this returns errors. `getter not found`  for this `char1: 'One', char2: 'Two', char3: 'Three'`. Also the return doesn't work as it expected `List<Widget>`.

Comment: The enums works now. But the return doesn't work as it expected `List<Widget>` With following error: `Error: A value of type 'Iterable<Set<RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>>>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<Widget>'.`

Comment: Ah yes. The mapping needs to be converted into a list with `toList()`. Please see if this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the spread operator and unwrap directly a for loop on your `Column`.

```
final List myList= ['One','Two','Thre' ];

    return Column(children: [
      for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++)
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: Text(myList[i]),
          value: SingingCharacter.values[i],
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
    ]);
```